# .NET reflection - check 2 classes are added as members of each other

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I check 2 classes are added as members of each other.

```
class Team
{
   Driver driver{ get; set;}
   Driver codriver{ get; set;}
}

class Driver
{
   Team parentTeam{ get; set;}
}
```

I have used the following way to get the properties:-

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
   ////if (!isParent) //need to find this.
   //{
   object propertyValue = property.GetValue(obj);
   if (propertyValue != null)
   {
      // Get the deep clone of the field in the original object and assign the clone to the field in the new object.
      property.SetValue(copiedObject, CloneProcedure(propertyValue));
   }
   //}
}
```

I want to skip through the first class which is a property in second when iterating through 2nd one.
Note: Some of you may feel my classes are declared incorrectly but this is a legacy system and there is no chance of me restructuring the classes.

I have tried DeclaringType and I get property.DeclaringType but obj.GetType().DeclaringType is null.

Comment: `GetType().DelcaringType` is for nested types

Comment: There is no "parent/child" relationship here. I think using those terms confuses the question. (Plus the spatial expression "back in the child object.") If you rephrase it as just saying what you want to do with two types it might be clearer.

Comment: Did you try using `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it you are deep cloning, and you don't actually want to skip a parent *Type*, you just don't want the same *instance* to generate multiple clones.

What you could do is keep a `Dictionary<object, object>` that keeps references of previously cloned instances:

```
object CloneProcedure(object o, Dictionary<object, object> cloned)
{
    object clone;
    if (cloned.TryGetValue(o, out clone))
    {
        // this object has been cloned earlier, return reference to that clone
        return clone;
    }

    clone = Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType());
    cloned[o] = clone;

    PropertyInfo[] properties = ...
    foreach ...
    {
        ...
        property.SetValue(copiedObject, CloneProcedure(propertyValue, cloned));
    }
}
```

This ensures that no object is ever cloned multiple times, and if multiple properties point to the same instance, the clones will also point to the same cloned instance.

Comment: This works Thanks. I have posted my entire copy utility below in case if anyone finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
   if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Parent)) 
   {
       object propertyValue = property.GetValue(obj);
       if (propertyValue != null)
       {
          // Get the deep clone of the field in the original object and assign the clone to the field in the new object.
          property.SetValue(copiedObject, CloneProcedure(propertyValue));
       }
   }
}
```

If you want to allow for inheritance, you can use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://www.google.com/search?q=isassignablefrom&oq=IsASs&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.3744j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Replace the word parent with the type you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my final Deep copy utility if this will benefit anyone

```
 public static class DeepCloneHelper
{
    private static string[] _excludedPropertyNames = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the deep clone of an object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the source.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">It is the object used to deep clone.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyNames"></param>
    /// <returns>Return the deep clone.</returns>
    public static T DeepClone<T>(T source, string[] propertyNames = null)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Object is null");
        }
        if (propertyNames != null) { _excludedPropertyNames = propertyNames; }
        return (T)CloneProcedure(source, new Dictionary<object, object>());
        // return target;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The method implements deep clone using reflection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">It is the object used to deep clone.</param>
    /// <param name="cloned"></param>
    /// <returns>Return the deep clone.</returns>
    private static object CloneProcedure(Object source, Dictionary<object, object> cloned)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        object clone;
        if (cloned.TryGetValue(source, out clone))
        {
            // this object has been cloned earlier, return reference to that clone
            return clone;
        }

        Type type = source.GetType();

        // If the type of object is the value type, we will always get a new object when 
        // the original object is assigned to another variable. So if the type of the 
        // object is primitive or enum, we just return the object. We will process the 
        // struct type subsequently because the struct type may contain the reference 
        // fields.
        // If the string variables contain the same chars, they always refer to the same 
        // string in the heap. So if the type of the object is string, we also return the 
        // object.
        if (type.IsPrimitive || type.IsEnum || type == typeof(string))
        {
            return source;
        }
        // If the type of the object is the Array, we use the CreateInstance method to get
        // a new instance of the array. We also process recursively this method in the 
        // elements of the original array because the type of the element may be the reference 
        // type.
        else if (type.IsArray)
        {
            Type typeElement = Type.GetType(type.FullName.Replace("[]", string.Empty) + "," + type.Assembly.FullName);
            var array = source as Array;
            Array copiedArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeElement, array.Length);
            cloned[source] = copiedArray;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                // Get the deep clone of the element in the original array and assign the 
                // clone to the new array.
                copiedArray.SetValue(CloneProcedure(array.GetValue(i), cloned), i);

            }
            return copiedArray;
        }

        else if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
            if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                var collection = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                cloned[source] = collection;

                foreach (var element in source as IEnumerable)
                {
                    collection.Add(CloneProcedure(element, cloned));
                }
                return collection;
            }
            else if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                var objectType = type.GetGenericArguments().Single();
                if (typeof(IList<>).MakeGenericType(objectType).IsAssignableFrom(type) ||
                    typeof(ISet<>).MakeGenericType(objectType).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                {
                    var collection = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    cloned[source] = collection;

                    var addMethod = collection.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
                    foreach (var element in source as IEnumerable)
                    {
                        addMethod.Invoke(collection, new[] { CloneProcedure(element, cloned) });
                    }
                    return collection;
                }
            }
            return source;
        }
        // If the type of the object is class or struct, it may contain the reference fields, 
        // so we use reflection and process recursively this method in the fields of the object 
        // to get the deep clone of the object. 
        // We use Type.IsValueType method here because there is no way to indicate directly whether 
        // the Type is a struct type.
        else if (type.IsClass || type.IsValueType)
        {
            object copiedObject = Activator.CreateInstance(source.GetType());
            cloned[source] = copiedObject;

            // Get all PropertyInfo.
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (_excludedPropertyNames == null || !_excludedPropertyNames.Contains(property.Name))
                {
                    object propertyValue = property.GetValue(source);
                    if (propertyValue != null && property.CanWrite && property.GetSetMethod() != null)
                    {
                        // Get the deep clone of the field in the original object and assign the 
                        // clone to the field in the new object.
                        property.SetValue(copiedObject, CloneProcedure(propertyValue, cloned));
                    }
                }
            }
            return copiedObject;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The object is unknown type");
        }
    }
}
```

Reference : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSDeepCloneObject-8a53311e